# How to reference xml file locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a solution with an ASP.NET project and a Class library project where the ASP.NET project depends on the Class library as a data access layer.

In my Class library project, I have SiteSetting.xml and c# code that's requesting the xml file as follows.

C# Code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("SiteSetting.xml");
```

When i launch my asp.net application and view the page that calls on the c# code above, I get an error saying "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\SiteSetting.xml'."

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ is obviously not where my c# code resides. My source code is in c:\Projects.. but where is compiled binaries of my ASP.NET and class library projects are executed? Better question is, how do i correctly reference SiteSetting.xml using relative paths in the context of ds.ReadXml()?

I want to use relative paths so that where my binaries are being executed will not an issue when finding SiteSetting.xml

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your input guys. Server.MapPath() is close but no cigar. Server.MapPath gives back a relative path in my ASP.NET project and not my c#, which is where my SiteSettings.xml resides.

So for example i have project called StackOverflow that has a C# project called "StackOverflow.Data" and an ASP.NET web project called "www" then i would have the following folders.

c:\Projects\StackOverflow
c:\Projects\StackOverflow\StackOverFlow.Data  <- Class Library project as my data access Layer
c:\Projects\StackOverflow\www <- ASP.NET project that calls on StackOverflow.Data classes and methods

Server.MapPath("~/SiteSettings.xml") return c:\Projects\StackOverflow\www\SiteSetting.xml. I need a way to get a path like c:\Projects\StackOverflow\StackOverflow.Data\SiteSetting.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your settings are in the class library. However, this is just the building environment for that library.

You need to think about your runtime environment, which is the Web Application and reference the file in the context of that.

Further more, it sounds like you might want to look into creating your own ConfigurationSection. See [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

If a config section is not appropriate, I would add an application setting to the web.config with a path to where your settings.xml file is and then in your class library, read that setting.

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingName"];
```

You might then need to map this path using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()

Comment: I had a feeling that this would be the solution i would get. It adds that small but extra layer of complexity in maintenance

Answer (score 9):

With MapPath? :

```
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SiteSetting.xml");
```

Comment: I have to admit that I copied it form somewhere else :p
But it's true that it's useful to have the full namespace in the answer.

Comment: Actually, `HttpContext.Current.Server` is not a namespace but a sequence of 3 static classes. And you don't need to type the first 2 because your Page object provides a `Server` property.

Comment: Good point. I knew that you didn't need the first two, but I never checked if it was a namespace or a sequence of classes.

Answer (score 3):

Anything 'local' should be addressed through MapPath. If it is in your Application root, use:

```
string filepath = Server.Mappath("~/SiteSetting.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

For an ASP.NET site you have the utility `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Settings.xml")`

This will return you the local file path for the file based on its relative location in your application.